# C# SQL Server Compact connection succeeds on first call, but not on second

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am a hobbyist programmer new to the world of OOP. In my quest to self teach, I am developing a small SQL based application. Since I plan to connect to the SQL Server Compact database multiple times, I decided to put it in its own class. The connection is successful the first time the class method is called, but the second time that same class method is called it throws an invalid path type exception. Best I can tell on the first run it finds the `.sdf` like it should, but on the second run its looking in the debug folder of visual studio's project file which of course is incorrect.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Horizon_CRM_Server
{
    public class sqlengine
    {
        public string sqlinst { get; set; }
        public string sqlpass { get; set; }
        public string sqlquery { get; set; }
        public string sqlquerytype { get; set; }
        public string[] sqldata { get; set; }
        public string[] sqlstringoutput { get; set; }
        public Int32 sqlintoutput { get; set; }

        public sqlengine() { }

        public void runsqlengine()
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection main_conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + this.sqlinst + ";Password=" + this.sqlpass))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL ENGINE CALLED");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    SqlCeCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlquery, main_conn);
                    sqlcommand.Connection.Open();

                    switch (this.sqlquerytype)
                    {
                        case "count":
                            Console.WriteLine("SQLENGINE COUNTING");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            this.sqlintoutput = (Int32)sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar();
                            Console.WriteLine("Initial Connection to Database Succeeded. There are " + this.sqlintoutput + " Users registered");
                            break;

                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlCeException ex)
                {
                    string expath = null;
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR:");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    try
                    {
                        string ez = ex.ToString();
                        expath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hhmmss_fff") + "HorizonCRM_ERR.txt";
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(expath, ez);

                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR HAS BEEN LOGGED TO: ");
                        Console.WriteLine(expath);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Could not log exception!");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex2);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: UNKNOWN!");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex3);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry crmhost = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress crmip = crmhost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localendpoint = new IPEndPoint(crmip, 11000);

            sqlengine sqlusers = new sqlengine();
            sqlusers.sqlinst = "crmDB.sdf";
            sqlusers.sqlpass = "4or1Z0n";
            sqlusers.sqlquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) Id FROM user_data";
            sqlusers.sqlquerytype = "count";

            sqlusers.runsqlengine();

            sqlengine sqlcustomers = new sqlengine();
            **sqlcustomers.sqlinst = "cmrDB.sdf";**
            sqlcustomers.sqlpass = "4or1Z0n";
            sqlcustomers.sqlquery = "SELECT COUNT (*) Id FROM customer_data";
            sqlcustomers.sqlquerytype = "count";

            sqlcustomers.runsqlengine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I could define the connection string directly, but want to keep the option to point this to a separate database file on startup if need be.

Am I going about this all wrong? Am I connecting to the compact edition database incorrectly?

Stack Overflow has been crucial to getting me this far, and I really appreciate the help everyone offers here.

Comment: On first call it's `"crmDB.sdf"` on second call it's `"cmrDB.sdf"`. "It is a good practice to store the connection string for your application in a [config file](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)". Also, you might want to adopt some [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229045.aspx) to make it easier to read you code. At least keep classes, properties and methods UpperCaseCamelCase. ^_^

Comment: Wow... I seriously spent the last two hours troubleshooting this.... I guess I needed a second pair of eyes. Much appreciated. I do plan on using config files to store data, but SQL is very new to me on the programming side, so I was just shooting for getting it to work in an OOP style before moving on. Thanks for the link too I'll do my best to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my pc and it works. I created a SQL Compact Edition database in Visual Studio using Project menu and Add New Item and selected Local Database. It works fine for the first query and the second query. I noticed you don't close the connection but I don't think this is the reason for your issue. On my pc the .sdf file is created in the project folder and is shown in Solution Explorer as part of the project. If your .sdf file is not included in the project maybe you can try to add it first and afterwards try your code.

Comment: It came down to a typo on the second call. I don't think I need to close the connection since I have it wrapped in a using statement. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You're right, the connection is closing when leaving the using statement. My mistake.